# iOS UI Automation deactivateAppForDuration failure

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I'm working on my first UI Automation script and am encountering a failure at the deactivateAppForDuration line below:

```
// Verify password field is shown when app is moved to the foreground
UIALogger.logMessage("move app to background");
target.deactivateAppForDuration(10);
UIALogger.logMessage("move app to foreground");
```

The error I get from Instruments is:

> Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().switcherScrollView().buttons()["TimeClock"]

What I see on the test device is that the app has been switched to the background and the iOS app switcher is showing. I can see my app (TimeClock). It appears from both the error message and the device screen that UI Automation isn't able to select my app for transition to the foreground.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there a work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works fine here. If you run the following code (nothing else) in a new Instruments file, does that work?

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
UIALogger.logMessage("move app to background");
target.deactivateAppForDuration(1);
UIALogger.logMessage("move app to foreground");
```

Please note: Instruments is *not* always showing you exactly *where* an error happens. Sometimes its a few lines above or below the line it's showing.
BUT: the *reason* why the error happens is correct. I admit that you have a bug in this line, that I guess you are calling after coming back from the Springboard:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().switcherScrollView().buttons()["TimeClock"]
```

Are you sure the element `switcherScrollView().buttons()["TimeClock"]` exists in your app and are accessible?

Comment: In this case, the `switcherScrollView()` represents the switcher control on the device itself, not in the app.  `switcherScrollView().buttons()["TimeClock"]` represents the icon for his app in the app switcher.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem.  Rebooting my device solved it for me.

Comment: Restarting simulator in this case, but that worked for me too.